# openSUSE Tumbleweed: How do I get sudo crontab -u root -e to open the root crontab in nano instead of vi?

Tags: bash, sudo, cron, environment-variables, opensuse

Just wondering the above.

So far I've tried:

```
export EDITOR=$(which nano)
export SUDO_EDITOR=$(which nano)
export VISUAL=$(which nano)
```

in both `~/.bashrc` and `/root/.bashrc`, as well as

```
Defaults        editor="/usr/bin/nano"
```

in `/etc/sudoers` and then logging out and back in again.

None of the above has worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Whose .bashrc? Yours or roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `export EDITOR=$(which nano)` in your homes `.bashrc`,
try `sudo -E crontab -e`.

You become root through sudo, so no need to specify the root-user for crontab.
The `-E` preserves your users environment.

Comment: That worked, thanks!